# Which \$\frac{V_{out}} {V_x}\$ is correct here? Mine or the author of the book?

Tags: transfer-function, miller-integrator

The following is from the book [Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf), Page 177.

*"Determine the transfer function of the circuit shown in Fig. 6.9(a) using (a) direct analysis and (b) Miller’s
approximation."*

I have two questions about this diagram.

[image]

**First you can see that when w pass \$\omega_z\$, the slope is flat. However, it should increase by 20dB/dec according to Bode's approximation.**

[image]

**Seondly, you can see that the capacitance is \$\frac{C_F} {A+1}\$ from the figure b.**

However, according to Miller's theorem.

$$Z_{out} = \frac{\frac{1} {s C_F}} {1 - (-1/A)} = \frac{1} {s C_F (1 + 1/A)}$$
$$\Rightarrow C_{out} = C_F (1 + \frac{1} {A})$$

[image]

$$V_{out} = - A V_x \frac{\frac{1} {s C_F (1 + 1/A)}} {R_{out} + \frac{1} {s C_F (1 + 1/A)}}
= -A V_x \frac{1} {s R_{out} C_F (1 + 1/A) + 1}
$$

$$\Rightarrow V_{out} = - A V_x \frac{A} {s R_{out} C_F (A + 1) + A}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {V_x} = - A \frac{A} {s R_{out} C_F (A + 1) + A}$$

However, the book gave
$$\frac{V_{out}} {V_x} = \frac{-A} {s R_{out} C_F \frac{1} {1 + A^{-1}} + 1}$$

which was different from what I calculated.

Comment: Q1 - No everything is correct. Notice that the pole makes -20dB and the zero increases the slope by +20dB. But the actual slope is at -20dB Thus -20dB + 20dB = 0dB. 
Q2 - Yes, you are right it's a typo in a book.

Comment: @G36 I don't think it's typo. It said  \$C_F /(1+ A^{−1})\$ at the output. But I think it should be \$C_F (1+ A^{−1})\$

Comment: You can call it a mistake/error if you don't like a "typo".

Comment: @G36 I have added \$\frac{V_{out}} {V_x}\$ in my question. Could you please have a look at \$\frac{V_{out}} {V_x}\$?

Comment: Are you sure about the denominator? I think it should be (A + 1)/A = (1 + A^-1) instead of 1/(1 + A^-1) = A/(A + 1)

Comment: @G36 Whose formula are you talking about? The book or mine? I am pretty sure my calculation is correct.

Comment: \$\omega\$ is the independent variable here. It increases at 1 decade per decade. Meaning, it is whatever it is, and we can analyze the circuit at whatever operating frequency we like. The dependent variable is \$A\$, the gain of the circuit.

Comment: Ok I see, I was talking about the book formula. And in your formula, you can divide the denominator by A.

Comment: @ThePhoton Do you agree with my \mbox{$\Large \frac{V_{out}}  {V_in}$}? Whose formula do you think is correct?

Comment: @G36 Do you mean the book is wrong in terms of \$\mbox{$\Large \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}}$}\$?

Comment: \$\omega\$ doesn't change at 20 dB/decade; it's fixed by the input signal source.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for pointing out. Could you please take a look at \$\mbox{$\Large\frac{V_{out}} {V_x}$}\$? Who is wrong? Me or the author of the book?

Comment: Before anything else I recommend that you fix your title and words on the image.

Comment: @Andyaka There are so many images. Which image are you talking about?

Comment: The bold words under the top image.

Comment: Your \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{x}}\$ is correct.

Comment: @G36 Could you please take a look at V.V.T answer? Why does he think there is negative resistance?

Comment: Because after we apply Miller's theorem we do not get a fully equivalent circuit. What we get is just an approximation solution.  Notice that now we have two poles circuit without zero. So for sure, this is not fully equivalent to the original circuit.

Answer (score 2):

It has become sort of a sport for electronics.SE posters to find "inconsistences" or even "errors" in Prof. Razavi's Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit, but the "finding" of this post replicates -- nearly verbatim -- the question [Value of output capacitance via Miller approximation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/664741/value-of-output-capacitance-via-miller-approximation). And yes, the output "Miller" capacitor value of Fig. 6.9(c) is in error, but the OP's formula is also incorrect: the output "Miller" impedance, with a non-zero output resistance of amplifier taken into account, is not purely capacitive, but has a negative-resistance contribution: \$Z_{Mout}=1/(jωC_f(1+A^{-1}))-R_{out}/(1+A)\$.

Have a positive view of these "inconsistences/typos": in great textbooks, even errors serve educational purpose well: you've got a chance to contribute to the text, let it be in the form of an item in the errata list or personal communication to the author.

Comment: If \$Z_{out}\$ is as what you have pointed out, the \$\frac{V_{out}} {V_x}\$ was not the same as what the book had written.

Comment: No, this formula does not contradict the textbook's formulas -- no exercise in the textbook derivates the formula that generalizes the Miller theorem for the case of non-ideal voltage sources. You were trying, and your formula is wrong. I derived the correct formula; you can see the details in my answer to the referenced SE question. If you doubt the correctness of my formula, you can try and derive it on your own or find the derivation elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

To answer just a part of your question:

It seems you have a confusion over the high-frequency behavior of the system.

The HF cutoff gain should be flat-band, not rising, due to the following equivalent circuit:

[image]

At high frequencies, capacitors become short circuits.  The amplifier itself may also trend towards zero gain (i.e., well above f<sub>T</sub>), thus giving the direct circuit as shown.

This remains true even if amplifier gain doesn't also drop to zero, because its transconductance effectively turns into an R<sub>out′</sub> = 1/g<sub>m</sub>; which may be in series with the internal R<sub>out</sub> depending on exact structure, but either way the equivalent circuit applies, just with different values.  Depending on where amplifier cutoff occurs, it may compound with the effect of this equivalent circuit (f<sub>T</sub> near f<sub>zero</sub>), or it may lead to a second plateau (f<sub>T</sub> well above f<sub>zero</sub>).

Yet another observation: if the feedback capacitor is effectively shorted out, then the amplifier reduces to a one-port, i.e. input and output ports are shorted together, and it can only affect the circuit by its resulting impedance; transfer characteristics are quite literally short-circuited.

(Also, I realize I'm using g<sub>m</sub> when the problem was given in terms of a Thevenin voltage output amplifier.  Real amplifying devices are closer to Norton sources, so it is better in general to use this model.  Given this equivalence, understand that either one can be used for this problem.  There may be particulars at work, where such a direct equivalence is not possible -- consider the assumptions underlying Miller's approximation to begin with -- but in that case, neither model will apply, and you're best off simulating with real (or at least better-representative) models in SPICE or what have you.  Since this is a simplified / toy model to discuss Miller's approximation, it's fine to use either format.)

Comment: Good explanation! Could you please take a look at \$\mbox{$\Large \frac{V_{out}} {V_x}$}\$ too? I and the book have different result.