# How can we calculate complex impedance when there is capacitor in the transistor circuit?

Tags: input-impedance

The following is from the book [book Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf), Page 187.

[image]

With the aid of Miller’s approximation, we have from Figure

$$Z_{in} = \frac{1} {\Biggr[C_{GS} + (1 + g_m R_D) C_{GD}\Biggr] s}$$

I have no idea how the author get this formula for \$Z_{in}\$.

The following what I have tried with Miller approximation.

[image]

Test voltage for this circuit.

[image]

Comment: Didn't you already get it right in your own attempt?

Comment: I don't think so. Shouldn't we consider the transistor?

Comment: In a sense, it is a follow-up to your question 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/696230/which-fracv-out-v-x-is-correct-here-mine-or-the-author-of-the-book , right? Yes, you're right, the transistor's \$r_o\$ contributes to both input and output impedances. The Miller formula should be modified, if the current source (as in this question) or the voltage source (as in your previous question) are not ideal. The resulting impedances are not purely capacitive and depend on the transistor/opamp output resistance.

Comment: @V.V.T Thank you for your explanation